# Android Studio on Mac - Can't access System Images from update sites

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am trying to get an Android development environment set up on my Mac.  I've downloaded Android Studio and have a project properly compiling without error.

The problem is when I've tried to create an emulator instance - It always reports that I don't have any system images available.

When trying to fix this issue, I noticed in the Preferences panel shown below that the system is unable to update from the System Images sites - it would seem that is the issue.  Hovering over the exclamation point says "File Not Found"  However, I do note that the .xml file is there if I paste it into a browser.

Is there a configuration piece I'm missing so that I can get these system images?  Or is this a mac issue?

[image]

Comment: I've made some progress by going into the standalone SDK Manager.  After toggling around in the preferences the Google System Images are finally showing up in the available packages list.  Not sure why they weren't there previously.

Comment: Specifically, I was toggling around in the Tools->Manage Add On Sites.  There was a Google entry in the User Defined area that I tried to delete but never went away until I went back into it.